# Unable to add event a in calender using phone gap in android 5.0.2

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to add event in device calender using phonegap. But when we add event in 5.0.2 device. i have got a message of add event successfully. but when i am searching on device calender. i am found "no events". and only particular 5.0.2 version i have face this problem. rather all android device working perfectly. and i also no able to add event in iphone. there is event add some time and some time not  but both case  not able to get notification.

for this functionality we are using following plug in:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin 
so, please suggest us a right plugin. which work on all device using phonegap.
thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried debugging your app? How did you achieve `add event successfully` ?

Comment: this message i have generated my self when my code is run with out error . and working on eclipse in phone gap .

Comment: What does it shows in Logcat when you run code?

Comment: do you know any other plugin. and plugin work for all type device like iphone, android , windows and blackberry devices. and also please send us installation process.